# Integrating spring services with old jsp web application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web.xml

I am new to Spring framework and would appreciate your guidance on a problem I am stuck with. I am working on development of web services based on Spring framework, which I have already developed separately on my local wrkspace, and now I am trying to integrate it with my existing web application which is basically using old jsps and no particular frameworks. My application is hosted on tomcat, and its original web.xml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
<display-name>BOBCAT</display-name>
<description>
BOBCAT
</description>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DFPServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>uk.co.blackwell.dfp.DFPServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>properties</param-name>
    <param-value>/opt/bobcat/dev2/apprunner/webapps/bobcat/WEB-INF/classes/uk/co/blackwell/dfp/dfpprops.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DFPServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.dfp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Cannot redirect to static apache-served pages -->
<!-- File not found (404),  unauthorized/forbidden (403, 401) -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/not_found.jsp</location>
</error-page>   
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/not_found.jsp</location>
</error-page>   
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/not_found.jsp</location>
</error-page>   
</web-app>
```

the new web.xml which I wanted to integrate within this old one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/restful-context.xml</param-value>            
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

I think I might be doing something terribly wrong in defining new web.xml itself, as when I put the chunks from the spring version to old version, it gives me 404 not found error for all the requests. I have tried consulting a lot of online resources but most of them are either supportive for new spring apps from scratch or are incomplete in some senses. Any help or efforts would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried several combinations and found that it was actually easier than thought. I am not using any listeners here, as it was giving 404 not found warning for all of the requests when I was trying to use the listener. I can get away with it as of now, as I just need to integrate restful web services using Spring with my legacy web application. It is working perfectly fine now, both on my local workspace (Win 7) as well as linux dev box.

The final web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>BOBCAT</display-name>
<description>
BOBCAT
</description>

<!-- Added on 20/03/2013 by Anshul for Spring -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/restful-context.xml</param-value>            
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- End of addition by Anshul -->


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DFPServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>uk.co.blackwell.dfp.DFPServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>properties</param-name>
    <param-value>/opt/bobcat/dev2/apprunner/webapps/bobcat/WEB-INF/classes/uk/co/blackwell/dfp/dfpprops.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DFPServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.dfp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Cannot redirect to static apache-served pages -->
<!-- File not found (404),  unauthorized/forbidden (403, 401) -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/not_found.jsp</location>
</error-page>   
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/not_found.jsp</location>
</error-page>   
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/not_found.jsp</location>
</error-page>   

</web-app>
```